# Duplicate definition with cocoapods, even though they aren't

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

After doing a `pod install` for a new pod, I'm getting a duplicate definition for the `AFURLRequestSerialization` protocol.

Yes, I understand that error. No, it's not defined somewhere[image: No, it's not defined somewhere].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `use_frameworks!` from the `Podfile` also removes the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` linker flag, which links in Swift frameworks into Objective-C code, even though it shouldn't. Solved.